# Why is the WSDL fetched by JAX-WS on every WS call?

Tags: web-services, netbeans, wsdl, jax-ws

I'm playing around with NetBeans and JAX-WS and I see that the WSDL is fetched every time a WS is called. Is there a way to avoid this? Is there some configuration?

Comment: I noticed that as well, I found it a bit silly.

Answer (score 4):

It is due to the support for late-binding and the myriad of configuration options that WS-Policy and other WSDL features bring to the table.

See the [JAX-WS RI FAQ](http://jax-ws.java.net/faq/index.html#wsdl_at_runtime).

For the trivial case, yes it is a bit silly and adds some overhead.  Once you get into a complex environment with multiple implementations running with slightly different configurations, it makes complete sense.