# SOAP Web Service: do you need the WSDL publication page?

Tags: web-services, api, soap, asmx

SOAP Web Service: do you need the WSDL publication page?

Can I remove the WSDL publication page? if so, will the client have any issues/problems consuming my web service?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may remove that page with no problems. However, you will have to supply the WSDL to your clients in some other manner. You can simply post the WSDL to some secure area of your web site, or even email it to them.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't need to read it from your service. The WSDL is a file. Serve this file from your web site, or send it in an email message: it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

Well that depends.
If the web service is not expected to change frequently you could provide the WSDL to clients so that they can cache it and use the cached WSDL at runtime.
Keep in mind that even though usually the users of the web service have generated static stubs from the wsdl, some frameworks access the WSDL at runtime for each service call (jax-ws does that [wsdl fetched on every call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008401/why-is-the-wsdl-fetched-by-jax-ws-on-every-ws-call)).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how public your webservice will be of course.

We have a webservice running that is (and should be) only used by our own applications, i.e. for checking valid licenses. We deliberately don't publish the WSDL pages because we don't want to make the interface to this licensing server more public then strictly needed.